# Fixing Zend Studio 8 Performance (typing lag) Issue

Tags: php, ide, zend-studio

Zend Studio 8 has performance problems with large php source files (around 3,000 lines of code) causing MAJOR typing lag. There has been a [patch developed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326261) but apparently they haven't rolled it out yet as nothing happens when I to go Help > Check for Updates.

Is there any way I can manually update the IDE so I don't have to wait for Zend?

Comment: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=8417

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ZS8 is a commercial product and only available for a few days now, you are likely still entitled to support. Please login to the Zend website and open a support ticket. They will get back to you and likely will provide you with a patch (if there is one) and instructions on how to install it.

Comment: I don't want to be mean but I asked them support for a ZS8 SVN issue and they were more preoccupied to sell me Zend Server than to solve the issue.

Comment: @Elzo My experience with them is quite good. They fixed a rather severe bug in my then ZS7 installation when UnitTesting wouldn't work via a Remote Session. And they provided a custom Zend Debugger DLL for me when I wanted to use a PHP version other than the bundled one.

Comment: It does indeed appear like there is a patch here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326261 but I don't know how to integrate it into my install. Also, I am using a trial version of Zend... so I don't know if I am entitled to support.

Comment: @Charles If you didnt buy it, you are not entitled support. But you can ask in http://forum.zend.com. See the link below your question.

Answer (score 5):

Zend Studio has a lot of performance issues because it is based on Eclipse  / PDT and Eclipse often exhibits performance problems.

You might want to consider Netbeans which has solid PHP support and less performance issues.

Comment: meah. zend = eclipse = netbeans = aptana = SUCKS. they all Java based and as such they are running inside JAVA VM which means they gonna be almost always slower then their NON-java competitors.

Comment: Eclipse has amazing features that makes it - while being a bit slow - incomparable. Unfortunately, the Zend folks were unable to port properly the Java version into PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Zend Finally released a beta fix for the issue. Steps to resolve the problem are as follows:

1. In Zend navigate to Help > Install new software
2. Update site: http://beta.zend.com/studio/8.0.1/update
3. Check all items in the features list
4. Uncheck the "update all repositories" checkbox and follow the wizard